# Can you process a tensor in chunks in a custom Keras loss function?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to write a cusom Keras loss function in which I process the tensors in sub-vector chunks. For example, if an output tensor represented a concatenation of quaternion coefficients (i.e. w,x,y,z,w,x,y,z...) I might wish to normalize each quaternion before calculating the mean squared error in a loss function like:

```
def norm_quat_mse(y_true, y_pred):
    diff = y_pred - y_true
    dist = 0
    for i in range(0,16,4):
        dist += K.sum( K.square(diff[i:i+4] / K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(diff[i:i+4])))))

    return dist/4
```

While Keras will accept this function without error and use in training, it outputs a different loss value from when applied as an independent function and when using model.predict(), so I suspect it is not working properly. None of the built-in Keras loss functions use this per-chunk processing approach, is it possible to do this within Keras' auto-differentiation framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
def norm_quat_mse(y_true, y_pred):
    diff = y_pred - y_true
    dist = 0
    for i in range(0,16,4):
        dist += K.sum( K.square(diff[:,i:i+4] / K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(diff[:,i:i+4])))))

    return dist/4
```

You need to know that `shape` of `y_true` and `y_pred` is `(batch_size, output_size)` so you need to skip first dimension during computations.